# Orange 3 - openSUSE 13.1 installation - No widgets

Tags: opensuse, orange

I am having trouble installing Orange3 from github on openSUSE 13.1.

I have all requirements installed: gcc, g++, python 3-devel, pysci, pyqt4devel etc.

I followed [these](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/wiki/Installation-on-openSUSE-13.2) instructions, everything seems to work (with many warnings when compiling), however when entering in `Orange.canvas`, there are no widgets at all. It seems they have been missing on installation/compilation.

Any idea about what I did miss in the install or requirements?

Comment: Start Orange with `python -m Orange.canvas -l3` to get a more detailed log and look for import errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the -l3 options.
All the widgets get the same error on import

```
  File "./Orange/widgets/utils/overlay.py", line 10, in <module>
import enum
```

ImportError: No module named 'enum'
Could not import 'orangecontrib.datafusion.widgets.owsamplematrix'``

I am not Python specialist, I will check for this module ..

Comment: Solved after adding the enum34 python3 module,strange on opensuse 13.1 it was not installed (maybe something to add in the installation instructions). Thanks Aleš Erjavec

Comment: Some widgets are missing and I get this error Orange/classification/_simple_tree.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, any idea ? Thanks